# How to compile a program on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: build-bpf, cargo

I'm trying to get up and running with Solana development and was hoping I could use my Raspberry Pi to do all my dev work (not a requirement, just an experiment). I've been following the tutorial series on Coding & Crypto (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=51S58xcHHBw) since it's pretty easy to follow.

When I go to compile my program with `cargo build-bpf` I'm presented with the following error:

```
/home/pi/.rustup/toolchains/bpf/bin/cargo: 1: ELF: not found
/home/pi/.rustup/toolchains/bpf/bin/cargo: 2: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

I then hopped on an old Linux laptop and tried to compile there, and after installing the toolset it seemed to compile just fine, minus a few warnings.

I'm assuming this is because I switched from an ARM to an x86 processor? Or is there some other dependency that's needed?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0nIEtIrG-k&list=PL53JxaGwWUqCr3xm4qvqbgpJ4Xbs4lCs7&index=3&ab_channel=Josh%27sDevBox

Follow the above link and you might be good.
The above error isn't occurring due to the requirements.
Its mostly due to some packages which are outdated.

Comment: That's an awesome tutorial! However the install script returns this error:
`downloading v1.14.2 installer
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403
solana-install-init: command failed: downloader https://release.solana.com/v1.14.2/solana-install-init-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu /tmp/tmp.a3ZBbfAdHp/solana-install-init`
A quick glance of the releases doesn't show that file as available. I'm attempting to build from source again to see if I missed something.